# SQL return Name's of people that have all done courses in list

Tags: sql-server

I need a SQL query that will allow me to return the values (students) that have done all the courses in a list.

For example:

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| Key | Name  | Course  |
+-----+-------+---------+
| 1   | Mike  | Maths   |
| 2   | Dave  | English |
| 3   | Chris | Science |
| 4   | Andy  | Maths   |
| 5   | Mike  | German  |
| 6   | Dave  | Science |
| 7   | Chris | English |
| 8   | Chris | Maths   |
| 9   | Dave  | Maths   |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

I need all the student names that have done **all** the courses in a list. The list will change with each query. As an exmple, I need the names of people that have done "English", "Maths" and "Science", which would return:

```
"Chris"
"Dave"
```

The list length may be any number of courses. The output will be used in other sql queries and is part of a much larger project, however to make it easier to understand I have tried to simplify my problem as much as possible.

I'm really scratching my head on how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `group by name` and put the conditions in the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clause:

```
select name
from tablename
where course in ('English', 'Maths', 'Science')
group by name
having count(distinct course) = 3
```

Answer (score -1):

I would consider re-evaluating your data model but based on what you provided this would work.

Basic solution:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Table T1 
LEFT JOIN Table T2 
ON T1.Name = T2.Name and T2.Course = 'Maths'
LEFT JOIN Table T3
ON T1.Name = T3.Name and T3.Course = 'English'
LEFT JOIN Table T3 
ON T1.Name = T4.Name and T4.Course = 'Science'
WHERE T2.Course IS NOT NULL AND T3.Course IS NOT NULL AND T4.Course IS NOT NULL
```

More generalized solution:

```
SELECT Name, [English], [Science], [Maths], [German]
FROM Table
PIVOT (max(Course) FOR Name IN ([English],[Science],[Maths],[German])) AS Pivot
WHERE [English] IS NOT NULL AND [Science] IS NOT NULL AND [Maths] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you but this is a massively simplified version of a far larger project. The values returned will then be used in a contains query to return other values. The list length and values will also be dynamic

Comment: If you're looking for the solution to a larger problem then you should post the entire problem or at least valid requirements

Comment: Ive updated the original description. Thanks for the help.